# Not generating and downloading HTML table data in CSV file in PHP with "header already added" error

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Dear Fellow PhP Experts,
I am writing below code to export HTML table data in PHP.
Its working nicely in **localhost**. However, when I deployed to the domain, there is warning-

> 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at ../result_month.php:64 *//dbconnect.php line//*) in
>   ../result_month.php on line 77 *//header("Location: $FileName") line//*'.

Seeking suggestion from you, what I am exactly doing wrong.

```
<?php require_once('dbconnect.php'); ?>

<?php           
    //To generate report, home page added below data to query desired information.
    $month=$_POST["themonth"];
    $year=$_POST["theyear"];
?>

<?php //I am not intended to redirect to new page when pressing export button
    if(isset($_POST["export"])) 
    {
        //as i am in the same page, need to generate query string again, that is why kept this month and year in hidden inputs
        $month_visit=$_POST["selected_month"];  
        $year_visit=$_POST["selected_year"];

        $FileName = "data_" . $month_visit . "_" . $year_visit . ".csv";

        header("Location: $FileName"); //its showing error in this line

        $output = fopen($FileName, 'w');

    // output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Name'));

    // fetch the data
        $query_string = "SELECT ID, Name from Participant";
        $rows = mysql_query($query_string); 

    // loop over the rows, outputting them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
            fputcsv($output, $row);

        fclose($output);
    }
?>

<form method="post"> // added this form at the top of HTML table to add export button
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_year" value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_month" value="<?php echo $month; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export to CSV" />
</form>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name from Participant");
echo "displaying query data in html table";
?>
```

Comment: is this you result.php page?

Comment: your `dbconnect.php` is throwing an error at line 64, probably a connection error that is printed on the page already, so php can't do the `header()` call any more

Comment: you are you open so much of php tag no need to close and reopen it.try iit include all code inside a single tag

Comment: yes it is result.php page @Shanukk

Comment: Is there any white space in your php page?before php tag?

Answer (score 0):

Any content without PHP open tag are treated as HTML, sent as HTTP_BODY.

HTTP_BODY will be sent after HTTP_HEADER was closed.

Try these codes:

```
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');

//To generate report, home page added below data to query desired information.
$month=$_POST["themonth"];
$year=$_POST["theyear"];

//I am not intended to redirect to new page when pressing export button
if(isset($_POST["export"])) 
{
    //as i am in the same page, need to generate query string again, that is why kept this month and year in hidden inputs
    $month_visit=$_POST["selected_month"];  
    $year_visit=$_POST["selected_year"];

    $FileName = "data_" . $month_visit . "_" . $year_visit . ".csv";

// WARNING : Uncomment this will cause header() call failed.
//echo "THIS IS HTTP_BODY";

    header("Location: $FileName"); //its showing error in this line

    $output = fopen($FileName, 'w');

// output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('ID', 'Name'));

// fetch the data
    $query_string = "SELECT ID, Name from Participant";
    $rows = mysql_query($query_string); 

// loop over the rows, outputting them
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
        fputcsv($output, $row);

    fclose($output);
}
?>
<form method="post"> // added this form at the top of HTML table to add export button
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_year" value="<?php echo $year; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_month" value="<?php echo $month; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export to CSV" />
</form>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Name from Participant");
echo "displaying query data in html table";
?>
```

Comment: I tried this way too. No change.
actually problem is header("Location: $FileName");
If i remove this line, then there is no error/ warning.
However, in localhost/ domain, without above header, no action (file downloading or showing in the browser ) triggers. I have found that to trigger force download the file, I must add headers.

Comment: Try to view the HTML source, and you might found another blank lines as they exists in included/required PHP files.